# Changed my default .pst and lost all folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007, pst

Since my main .pst (Outlook 2007) was really big (close to 20gb) I decided to just create a new one for all my new emails.

The problem now is that my old .pst was full of folders I created and now they're gone. All the mails are there but only in the "Incoming" folders.

I really don't know what happened, is there a way to recover my folders ?

Comment: Sounds like you overwrote the existing .pst file with a blank file, is that the case?  Does your existing file even still exist?

Comment: Yes and it is the same size, 20gb. The new one I created has a different name.

Comment: Both the new .PST and the old .PST are listed, and you have tried, switching which pst file is the default?  I have 8 .PST files and they are just separated by their names?  You sure just not overlooking the obvious?